# Camel quickfixj - setting a DataDictionary - I can't?

Tags: apache-camel

Try as I might I cannot seem to make quickfixj take a dictionary - or indeed give any sign its registered the dictionary at all, I have no choice but to use the dictionary and it is not something I have control over. I've tried various uses of the DataDictionary property which is in the documentation and in quickfixJEndpoint class, but I really expect to set it on the endpoint, but dont seem to have any way to do that

I have an accpetor A 
and an initiator B

I want to send a message from acceptor to intitiator via A->B 
send an ack back from initiator to accpetor via B->A

The last place it 'works' is just before sending to the fix endpoint A->B

The initiator and acceptor connect, handshake and log-on with no problem, then the acceptor constructs its non-standard fix-message and send it, right before it sends is the last time before an exception occurs.

It includes a tag '15' which is causing a problem because the type it is being used on does not normally include 15, but with the DataDictionary it does - but it isn't loading the dictionary and quickfixj is throwing an invalidField exception because it doesn't like tag 15 being there since its not on the base-type.

I set on the exchange everything I can to make it acknowledge the datadictionary, everywhere I can

on route
in process {

```
TradeCaptureReport fix = new TradeCaptureReport();

fix.setString( 15, "my value" );

....

exchange.setProperty( QuickfixJEndpoint.DATA_DICTIONARY_KEY, "mydictionary.xml" )
exchange.getOut().setProperty( QuickfixJEndpoint.DATA_DICTIONARY_KEY, "mydictionary.xml" )
```

exchange.getOut().setBody( fix );
}

```
  quickfix.FieldException: Tag not defined for this message type, 
 B->A   , error> (Reject sent for Message 2: Tag not defined for this message type:15)
```

It never reaches the code inside the acceptor which would normally receive A->B and return B->A as a response, so although it report B->A and think that is incorrect

I hope I've given enough info here. scratching my brain for how to get quickfixj to pick up this dictionary.

Oh, the resource definietly exists, although nothing indicates it ever even tries to look for it, it definitely doesn't seem to be hitting anyything 'in the code' to indicate that it has done anything to look for a DataDictionary.

Any ideas how I can set a DataDictionary

The last place it 'works' is at A->B, I define the fix-message but it craps-out when I send it. the error message is reported on B->A - which is a bit wierd, then again, there's a LOT of stack trace, it definietly doesn't get into the code of the reciever

Answer (score 0):

I solved myself by avoiding camel's mechanism to do DataDictionary, which as of 2.11.2 doesn't seem to work and just set the dictionary in the settings file. Works.